How to match patterns in a column of longer strings using dplyr
I am trying to pattern-match all my targeted tissues ("heart", "muscle", "kidney", "liver") in a data frame (pasted below) and list the name of species that have all of the targeted tissues.
Data:
df <- read.csv(text =
"Species,Tissue
Human,Kr_liver_2
Human,Heart
Human,Liver_556
Human,Kr_Kidney_2
Human,Kr_Muscle_2
Human,Kr_Brain_2
Mouse,Brain
Mouse,Kr_liver_3
Mouse,Kr_liver_5
Mouse,Kr_liver_27")

I tried the approach below but I got an empty output, however, the desired output based on the data frame above should be 'Human' because it has all of the targetted tissues.
Tissue_check <- df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(all(grepl(paste(target_tissues, collapse = "|"), tolower(Tissue)))) %>%
  pull(Species) %>%
  unique()

How can I achieve this?

The filter you have is checking whether, in each group, all elements of df$Tissue contain one of the elements of target_tissues, which is different from what you are expecting. You get empty output as rows 6 and 7 do not contain a target tissue.

You can paste all elements of Tissue column into one string, and detect if all of the target tissues are included in it.
library(dplyr)

target <- c("heart", "muscle", "kidney", "liver")

df %>%
  filter(all(sapply(target, grepl, toString(Tissue), ignore.case = TRUE)),
         .by = Species)

An alternative with stringr:
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(all(str_detect(toString(Tissue), fixed(target, ignore_case = TRUE))),
         .by = Species)

Output
#   Species      Tissue
# 1   Human  Kr_liver_2
# 2   Human       Heart
# 3   Human   Liver_556
# 4   Human Kr_Kidney_2
# 5   Human Kr_Muscle_2
# 6   Human  Kr_Brain_2


You could check lengths of the intersect.
> tt <- c("heart", "muscle", "kidney", "liver")
> transform(dat,
+           foo=ave(tolower(Tissue), Species, 
+                   FUN=\(x) identical(
+                     length(intersect(
+                       gsub(sprintf('.*(%s).*', paste(tt, collapse='|')), '\\1', x),
+                       tt)),
+                     length(tt)))) |> 
+   subset(foo == TRUE, select=Species) |> unique()
  Species
1   Human


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Species = c("Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", 
"Human", "Human", "Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse", "Mouse"), Tissue = c("Kr_liver_2", 
"Heart", "Liver_556", "Kr_Kidney_2", "Kr_Muscle_2", "Kr_Brain_2", 
"Brain", "Kr_liver_3", "Kr_liver_5", "Kr_liver_27")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

